# Why are my wp urls showing page not found?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages, urls

I recently changed a page slug url in the edit area and saved it from flood-maps to floodmaps.

There was an issue here so I then deleted the page in trash too and started a new one with the same name Flood maps. I added the content and then saved it.

When I went to go to the url it gave me a page error and the url went back to the old slug url floodmaps which is not found. I then queried in the mysql db and got rid of _wp_old_slug in the post meta table.

Now when I try to load floodmaps I get the error.

I have checked plugins etc and resaved permalinks and still nothing works.

Is there anything that can inspect the issue here?

Cheers

Comment: is it something related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880976/403-error-wordpress-link-not-working-when-permalink-setting-is-set-to-post-na/17931522#17931522

Comment: Hi, no its not that as I have checked the db for the old slugs and flushed the permalinks several times in the site